# Remove part of the link to all pages of the site by PHP

Tags: php

i see this code , to add www for all pages

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.') === 0 ) {
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://' . substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
} elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.') !== 0 ) {
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
}
```

i want edit it to remove part from link to all pages of the site , links in my site like `../index.php?styleid=1` i want remove `?styleid=x` or `&styleid=x` if exist on my links

Comment: use `SCRIPT_NAME` instead of `REQUEST_URI`, then.

Comment: You could manage that in a `.htaccess`-file

Comment: @MarcB , i cannot understand you , can you gave me exmpel

Comment: @pbaldauf, i know but i want do it by php

Comment: @omardealo Ok, it's up to you